# Jquery Select value from a dropdown box(NOT SHOWING) on the email

Tags: php, html, jquery, select, dropdown

I have a dropdown form that i generate with a for loop in php and i am trying to get the selected value which is a date to be send by email

On the index page i have basically like below. It's not the full code because my loop is more complex but i don't believe the problem is there.

on my custom.js  file i have as below. The issue must be on the reservation date select on the below code. I am not that good with jquery and it must be something silly probably.

All inputs i get them correctly. My issue is with the select dropdown box.

What i am doing wrong?

my last file its the send.php which just sends the email. Nothing wrong there as well as all fields are sent correctly besides the reservation date.

As an input radio box which i had the code before the date works. But inside a dynamically created with php select dropdown box it doesn't.

The send.php sends all the info besides Reservation date here the output of send.php /send.php?firstname=Demetris&lastname=Demetriou&amount=2&mobilephone=99999&email=email%40gmail.com&message=somenotes

In the snippet it shows the output of the my php foreach and for loops. Its done in php. No issues there.

I am not sure or its not working this part of the code var reservationDate = $contactform.find('select[name="add_r_date"]:selected').val();

```js
$('#send').live("click", function() {
  var url = 'send.php';
  var error = 0;
  var $contactpage = $(this).closest('.ui-page');
  var $contactform = $(this).closest('.contact-form');
  $('.required', $contactform).each(function(i) {
    if ($(this).val() === '') {
      error++;
    }
  });
  // each
  if (error > 0) {
    alert('Please fill in all the mandatory fields. Mandatory fields are marked with an asterisk *.');
  } else {
    var firstname = $contactform.find('input[name="add_name"]').val();
    var lastname = $contactform.find('input[name="add_surname"]').val();
    var amount = $contactform.find('input[name="add_seats"]:checked').val();
    var reservationDate = $contactform.find('select[name="add_r_date"]:selected').val();
    var mobilephone = $contactform.find('input[name="add_phone"]').val();
    var email = $contactform.find('input[name="email"]').val();
    var message = $contactform.find('input[name="add_note"]').val();

    //submit the form.send.php takes from below.
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: url,
      data: {
        firstname: firstname,
        lastname: lastname,
        //  state : state,
        amount: amount,
        reservationDate: reservationDate,
        mobilephone: mobilephone,
        email: email,
        message: message
      },
      success: function(data) {
        if (data == 'success') {
          console.log(data);
          // show thank you
          window.location = 'thankyou.php'
          //$contactpage.find('.contact-thankyou').show();
          //$contactpage.find('.contact-form').hide();
        } else {
          alert('Unable to send your message. Please try again.');
        }
      }
    });
    //$.ajax

  }
  return false;
});
```

```html
<form action="" id="add-form" class="contact-form">

  <label class="col-lg-12 control-label"><strong>Dates:</strong></label>
  <select name="add_r_date" id="add_r_date">Friday,31 Mar
    <option value="2023-03-31">Friday,31 Mar</option>Saturday,01 Apr
    <option value="2023-04-01">Saturday,01 Apr</option>Sunday,02 Apr
    <option value="2023-04-02">Sunday,02 Apr</option>Monday,03 Apr
    <option value="2023-04-03">Monday,03 Apr</option>Tuesday,04 Apr
    <option value="2023-04-04">Tuesday,04 Apr</option>Wednesday,05 Apr
    <option value="2023-04-05">Wednesday,05 Apr</option>Thursday,06 Apr
    <option value="2023-04-06">Thursday,06 Apr</option>Friday,07 Apr
    <option value="2023-04-07">Friday,07 Apr</option>Saturday,08 Apr
    <option value="2023-04-08">Saturday,08 Apr</option>Sunday,09 Apr
    <option value="2023-04-09">Sunday,09 Apr</option>Monday,10 Apr
    <option value="2023-04-10">Monday,10 Apr</option>Tuesday,11 Apr
    <option value="2023-04-11">Tuesday,11 Apr</option>Wednesday,12 Apr
    <option value="2023-04-12">Wednesday,12 Apr</option>Thursday,13 Apr
    <option value="2023-04-13">Thursday,13 Apr</option>Friday,14 Apr
    <option value="2023-04-14">Friday,14 Apr</option>Saturday,15 Apr
    <option value="2023-04-15">Saturday,15 Apr</option>Sunday,16 Apr
    <option value="2023-04-16">Sunday,16 Apr</option>Monday,17 Apr
    <option value="2023-04-17">Monday,17 Apr</option>Tuesday,18 Apr
    <option value="2023-04-18">Tuesday,18 Apr</option>Wednesday,19 Apr
    <option value="2023-04-19">Wednesday,19 Apr</option>Thursday,20 Apr
    <option value="2023-04-20">Thursday,20 Apr</option>Friday,21 Apr
    <option value="2023-04-21">Friday,21 Apr</option>Saturday,22 Apr
    <option value="2023-04-22">Saturday,22 Apr</option>Sunday,23 Apr
    <option value="2023-04-23">Sunday,23 Apr</option>Monday,24 Apr
    <option value="2023-04-24">Monday,24 Apr</option>Tuesday,25 Apr
    <option value="2023-04-25">Tuesday,25 Apr</option>Wednesday,26 Apr
    <option value="2023-04-26">Wednesday,26 Apr</option>Thursday,27 Apr
    <option value="2023-04-27">Thursday,27 Apr</option>Friday,28 Apr
    <option value="2023-04-28">Friday,28 Apr</option>Saturday,29 Apr
    <option value="2023-04-29">Saturday,29 Apr</option>Sunday,30 Apr
    <option value="2023-04-30">Sunday,30 Apr</option>Monday,01 May
    <option value="2023-05-01">Monday,01 May</option>Tuesday,02 May
    <option value="2023-05-02">Tuesday,02 May</option>Wednesday,03 May
    <option value="2023-05-03">Wednesday,03 May</option>Thursday,04 May
    <option value="2023-05-04">Thursday,04 May</option>Friday,05 May
    <option value="2023-05-05">Friday,05 May</option>Saturday,06 May
    <option value="2023-05-06">Saturday,06 May</option>Sunday,07 May
    <option value="2023-05-07">Sunday,07 May</option>Monday,08 May
    <option value="2023-05-08">Monday,08 May</option>Tuesday,09 May
    <option value="2023-05-09">Tuesday,09 May</option>Wednesday,10 May
    <option value="2023-05-10">Wednesday,10 May</option>Thursday,11 May
    <option value="2023-05-11">Thursday,11 May</option>Friday,12 May
    <option value="2023-05-12">Friday,12 May</option>Saturday,13 May
    <option value="2023-05-13">Saturday,13 May</option>Sunday,14 May
    <option value="2023-05-14">Sunday,14 May</option>Monday,15 May
    <option value="2023-05-15">Monday,15 May</option>Tuesday,16 May
    <option value="2023-05-16">Tuesday,16 May</option>Wednesday,17 May
    <option value="2023-05-17">Wednesday,17 May</option>Thursday,18 May
    <option value="2023-05-18">Thursday,18 May</option>Friday,19 May
    <option value="2023-05-19">Friday,19 May</option>Saturday,20 May
    <option value="2023-05-20">Saturday,20 May</option>Sunday,21 May
    <option value="2023-05-21">Sunday,21 May</option>Monday,22 May
    <option value="2023-05-22">Monday,22 May</option>Tuesday,23 May
    <option value="2023-05-23">Tuesday,23 May</option>Wednesday,24 May
    <option value="2023-05-24">Wednesday,24 May</option>Thursday,25 May
    <option value="2023-05-25">Thursday,25 May</option>Friday,26 May
    <option value="2023-05-26">Friday,26 May</option>Saturday,27 May
    <option value="2023-05-27">Saturday,27 May</option>Sunday,28 May
    <option value="2023-05-28">Sunday,28 May</option>Monday,29 May
    <option value="2023-05-29">Monday,29 May</option>Tuesday,30 May
    <option value="2023-05-30">Tuesday,30 May</option>
  </select>




</form>
```

Comment: Your php for loop is missing a closing `}`. And`<?php ... ?>`

Comment: Wasn't `.live()` deprecated and remove years ago?

Comment: @brombeer that not my full code .. Its just the part that needed to show. The dropdown box its shows fine.

Comment: @bassxzero Yes ,, But that's not the problem since its working fine for all the other inputs.

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please remove the PHP and post RENDERED html in a [mcve]

Comment: So many things here. Why use JavaScript at all. 
1. Add the `required` keyword to the form elements and make sure the first value in the select has `value=""` 2. redirect to thankyou on the server using the `header('location: ...');`

Comment: IF you want to use JavaScript why not generate the select on the client and then ajax in the thankyou page without redirecting?

Comment: @mplungjan thanks.. But the date comes from php . I dont know how i can do that in html .. here is the php for $day .... $day=date('l,d M',strtotime("+$i day"));

Comment: @mplungjan i am using ajax like you said. That part works fine.. I am using ajax to store the selected  and typed info to db.. Thats working with no issues.. The problem is sending the emails once they press Reserve.All the info shows correctly on the email besides that reservation Date.

Comment: "_besides that reservation Date_" What do you get as reservation date? Is it empty?

Comment: @brombeer Yes empty... I tried putting as value ='123'  and still it doesnt show on the email.. On the database it goes fine.

Comment: Just to recap: send.php saves the value fine into your database but it doesn't show up correctly in an email? What does send.php look like?

Comment: @brombeer .. No send.php just sends the email.  It sends all the fields with no issues besides the reservation date.. I am using ajax on the same index.php page to store to database.

Comment: @brombeer what i am not sure if its correct or its atleast not working its this part -> var reservationDate = $contactform.find('select[name="add_r_date"]:selected').val();

Comment: You could simply `console.log(reservationDate)` to see its value. Or use your browsers DevTools/Networking tab to see your AJAX request/data

Comment: @brombeer . i tried that but since i am redirecting to thankyou.php it doesnt show. Ok . I will stop the redirection just to test .. I posted the link to the full code for my php loop as i had a different issue before and solved at stackoverflow.

Comment: @brombeer i posted above the output url that goes to send.php.. The reservation date is missing completely.

Comment: FYI you can tick the "preserve log" box in your developer tools so it doesn't destroy all the previous logs when the page refreshes or redirects. That can make it easier to see what's happening.

Comment: I agree though that if you're just going to redirect immediately when the AJAX request finishes, it was a bit pointless to have the overhead of AJAX to begin with. The whole point of AJAX is to allow you to stay on the same page instead of refreshing or redirecting. You could make your code and your debugging process a lot simpler by just submitting the form directly without Javascript or AJAX.

Comment: I'd also strongly recommend submitting it as a POST rather than a GET, especially with this amount of data and with dates and so on involved. It can get a bit mucky putting all that in the URL parameters. I don't have time to look it  up now but I vaguely remember some issues with date strings in URL parameters being a pain...can't recall the details but it's possible it could be relevant. Difficult to know since you've shown us nothing from your debugging efforts.

Comment: Also in the developer tools check the "Preserve log" checkbox

Answer (score 2):

Ok finally i solved the problem.

I changed this line of code

```
var reservationDate = $contactform.find('select[name="add_r_date"]:selected').val();
```

to this

```
var reservationDate = $contactform.find('#add_r_date option:selected').val();
```

Before that i also changed from GET method to POST method as some here suggested. Thanks. But that alone didnt solve the problem until i changed the above line. I am using jquery 1.12. Thanks all for trying to help.